# redirection after clicking submit

Tags: java, spring, jsp, redirect

I have a web application, that, for the moment, contains only, login form and registration form. I am using spring MVC/security and hibernate.

After filling the registration form and clicking submit, I want to redirect to the login page, so the user can log in. 
And that's the problem.

[image: Here's the registration.jsp]

[image: And here's the controller]

Thank you.

Comment: Please post code as code, not as screenshots. Also if you want to redirect, then redirect. `return redirect:/url-to-login-page`.

Comment: Both of your Controllers methods are returning `"registration"`

Comment: Thank you so much, it works

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right, the registration is done in "registration.jsp"and after the methods for the registration are executed, you want to redirect to the login page. Assuming your login page is **"login.jsp"** then you return in the method **"newUser()"** should be **"login"**

the way you return a value, I assume as well that you have a viewResolver bean adding your prefix and suffix

```
public String newUser(ModelMap model) {
    User user = new User();
     ... ...
    return "login";
```

Comment: glad to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the login page is "login.jsp" and your view resolver is mapped to prefix .jsp, Your SaveUser method should return "login"